# How can I debug a single Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I know how to debug when using React but have no clue how to do it with a single Javascript file. I'd like to do it in my text editor, Atom, but if there's a good online editor I can use that would also be great.

I know I can use Chrome Dev Tools but I would love some sort of autocomplete feature that it doesn't provide. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [visual studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/)

Comment: https://playcode.io/ has good intellisense

Comment: If you use Chrome, VSCode has a technique for that: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code.  I imagine Atom does as well, using the Chrome Debugger Protocol.  (**Update**: yes it does: https://atom.io/packages/xatom-debug-chrome.  I've never tried it though.)

Comment: What exactly do you do when debugging a react project? Why do you think debugging a single script is any different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many ways to debug **JS-Files**.

1. Install the [ESlint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) plugin in your IDE
2. [Dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript)
3. Just type **[debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)** in your **JS-File**
4. Install [ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started) in your Project

I hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

If your browser supports debugging, you can use console.log() to display JavaScript values in the debugger window.
exemple

```js
a = 5;
b = 6;
c = a + b;
console.log(c);
```

In the debugger window, you can set breakpoints in the JavaScript code.
At each breakpoint, JavaScript will stop executing, and let you examine JavaScript values.
After examining values, you can resume the execution of code (typically with a play button).

You can also use the debugger keyword stops the execution of JavaScript, and calls (if available) the debugging function.
This has the same function as setting a breakpoint in the debugger.
If no debugging is available, the debugger statement has no effect.
With the debugger turned on, this code will stop executing before it executes the third line.

```js
var x = 15 * 5;
debugger;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Thank you for a well-written answer on your first try.... however, I think this misses the point of the question.  The poster was asking how to debug using the editor rather than the browser developer tools.